# JavaScript to choose droplist value not working in ASP .NET MVC4 with HTMLHelper and "All"

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using JavaScript to get the selected value of a drop list in MVC 4 but have an issue I think is caused by the HTMLHelper.

CONTROLLER - to populate droplist

```
private string PopulateStandard(object selectedValue = null)
{
    var query = db.Database
                  .SqlQuery<StandardModel>(
                        "SELECT * FROM [DBO].[GetStandards] ('" + 
                        User.Identity.Name + "', '" + DateTime.UtcNow + "')")
                  .ToList();

    ViewBag.Standard = new SelectList(query, "Standard", "Standard", selectedValue);

    try { return query[0].Standard; }
    catch { return ""; }
}
```

VIEW

The view has this section for the drop list. Please note the inclusion of "All". I think this is the problem.  That puts a first row atop the drop list saying "All" with a null value. I want that. So far so good (so what)

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Standard)
@Html.DropDownList("Standard", "All")
```

JAVASCRIPT

It's a long story, but I have other code that requires me to get the value of the drop list using JavaScript, so I'm doing it like this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("Standard");
var sStandard = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

PROBLEM

If no value was chosen, then I should get the first row, which would be "All" for text or "" for value. Instead, I'm getting the second row, which is the first one with data as populated from the database.

Is the HTML helper causing me to not get the first row? Or is my JavaScript off?

EDIT - to show ViewSource on drop list

These are the first few lines of the rendered list

```
<select id="Standard" name="Standard"><option value="">All</option>
<option value="2S">2S</option>
<option value="Aero">Aero</option>
```

Comment: It would probably help to see the HTML generated for the first couple of options--edited if you don't want to give out too much info, of course. I see a few scenarios this problem could pan out to be.

Comment: I went around this by not letting the HTML helper add "All" and doing it from the datasource instead. Kind of a hack. My problem is solved by this question isn't answered so I'll leave it if anyone wants to duplicate and solve it.

Answer (score 1):

**@Html.DropDownList("Standard", "All")**

here ***"All"*** is option label. so you do not get this as value.